# Parse JSON file using Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've the **JSON source data** file as like below and i'll need the **Expected Results** in a quite different format which is also shown below, is there a way i can achieve this using Spark Scala. Appreciate your help on this

JSON source data file

```
{
  "APP": [
    {
      "E": 1566799999225,
      "V": 44.0
    },
    {
      "E": 1566800002758,
      "V": 61.0
    }
  ],
  "ASP": [
    {
      "E": 1566800009446,
      "V": 23.399999618530273
    }
  ],
  "TT": 0,
  "TVD": [
    {
      "E": 1566799964040,
      "V": 50876515
    }
  ],
  "VIN": "FU74HZ501740XXXXX"
}
```

Expected Results:

[image]

JSON Schema:

```
|-- APP: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- ASP: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- ATO: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
|-- RPM: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
|-- TT: long (nullable = true)
|-- TVD: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
|-- VIN: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by reading your json file:

```scala
  val inputDataFrame: DataFrame = sparkSession
    .read
      .option("multiline", true)
      .json(yourJsonPath)
```

Then you can create a simple rule to get `APP, ASP, ATO`, since it's the only fields in the input that have a struct datatype:

```scala
val inputDataFrameFields: Array[StructField] = inputDataFrame.schema.fields

  var snColumn = new Array[String](inputDataFrame.schema.length)

   for( x <- 0 to (inputDataFrame.schema.length -1)) {

    if(inputDataFrameFields.apply(x).dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType] && !inputDataFrameFields.apply(x).name.isEmpty) {
     snColumn(x) = inputDataFrameFields.apply(x).name
    }
  }
```

Then you create your empty dataframe as follow and populate it:

```scala
  val outputSchema = StructType(
    List(
      StructField("VIN", StringType, true),
      StructField(
        "EVENTS",
        ArrayType(
          StructType(Array(
            StructField("SN", StringType, true),
            StructField("E", IntegerType, true),
            StructField("V", DoubleType, true)
          )))),
      StructField("TT", StringType, true)
    )
  )

  val outputDataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], outputSchema)
```

Then you need to create some udfs to parse your input and do the correct mapping.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution to parse a json to a spark dataframe adapted to your data :

```
    val input = "{\"APP\":[{\"E\":1566799999225,\"V\":44.0},{\"E\":1566800002758,\"V\":61.0}],\"ASP\":[{\"E\":1566800009446,\"V\":23.399999618530273}],\"TT\":0,\"TVD\":[{\"E\":1566799964040,\"V\":50876515}],\"VIN\":\"FU74HZ501740XXXXX\"}"

    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val outputDataFrame = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", true).option("mode","PERMISSIVE")
      .json(Seq(input).toDS)
        .withColumn("APP", explode(col("APP")))
      .withColumn("ASP", explode(col("ASP")))
      .withColumn("TVD", explode(col("TVD")))
        .select(
          col("VIN"),col("TT"),
          col("APP").getItem("E").as("APP_E"),
          col("APP").getItem("V").as("APP_V"),
          col("ASP").getItem("E").as("ASP_E"),
          col("ASP").getItem("V").as("ASP_E"),
          col("TVD").getItem("E").as("TVD_E"),
          col("TVD").getItem("V").as("TVD_E")
        )

    outputDataFrame.show(truncate = false)

    /*
+-----------------+---+-------------+-----+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
|VIN              |TT |APP_E        |APP_V|ASP_E        |ASP_E             |TVD_E        |TVD_E   |
+-----------------+---+-------------+-----+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
|FU74HZ501740XXXXX|0  |1566799999225|44.0 |1566800009446|23.399999618530273|1566799964040|50876515|
|FU74HZ501740XXXXX|0  |1566800002758|61.0 |1566800009446|23.399999618530273|1566799964040|50876515|
+-----------------+---+-------------+-----+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------+
     */
```

Comment: Hello @SimbaPK, i no need data in structured format. I need the data in a JSON format as shown in the Expected Results. Any help would be much appreciated.